# Uncertain separator, parsing a messy log with sed

Tags: sed, text-parsing

I'm working on #huge# text files (from 100mb to 1gb), I have to parse them to extract some particoular data. The annoying thing is that the files have not a clearly defined separator.

For example:

```
"element" 123124 16758 "12.4" "element" "element with white spaces inside" "element"
```

I have to delete the white spaces in strings limited by " (quote), the problem is that I must not erase the white spaces "outside" the quotes (otherwise some numbers would merge).
I can't find a decent sed solution, can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you use awk, not sed. And there's certainly no need to create your own C program, as `awk` is already an excellent C program to do file processing, even on GB files. So here's a one liner to do the job.

```
$ more file
"element" 123124 16758 "12.4" "element" "element with white spaces inside" "element"

$ awk -F'"' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) {gsub(/ +/,"",$i)}}1' OFS='"' file
"element" 123124 16758 "12.4" "element" "elementwithwhitespacesinside" "element"
```

Comment: That solved my problem. Just a last request, can you please explain me the code? Thank you very much (I'm not that familiar with awk)

Comment: by setting double quotes as the field separator, those words inside the quotes have field numbers that are even. Hence the `i` counter increases by 2. `gsub()` substitutes all spaces to null. Pls read the gawk manual (search GNU awk) for more info

Answer (score 1):

I can't come up with a sed solution, however you might be better off just writing a small application to do this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string line;
    while(getline(cin,line)) {
        bool inquot = false;
        for(string::iterator i = line.begin(); i != line.end(); i++) {
            char c = *i;
            if (c == '"') inquot = !inquot;

            if (c != ' ' || !inquot) cout << c;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then go

`./a.out < test.log > new.out`

**DISCLAIMER**

This will completely choke if you have escaped quotes on lines or multiline things within quotes.

For instance
`"The word \"word\" is weird"`
and things to that effect will cause problems

Answer (score 1):

Like Jamie, I don't think sed is good for the job. It could be that my sed skill is not good enough for the job. Here is a solution which essentially the same as Jamie's, but in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Script to delete spaces within the double quotes, but not outside.

QUOTE = '"'
SPACE = ' '

file = open('data', 'r')
for line in file:
    line = line.rstrip('\r\n')
    newline = ''
    inside_quote = False
    for char in list(line):
        if char == QUOTE:
            inside_quote = not inside_quote
        if not (char == SPACE and inside_quote):
            newline += char
    print(newline)
file.close()
```

Save this script to a file, say rmspaces.py. You can then invoke the script from the command line:

```
python rmspaces.py
```

Note that the script assumes the data is in a file called *data*. You can modify the script to taste.